# How to combine 3 different sheets with Query(importrange)?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to combine 3 different sheets of data from range A2:O Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 using `Query(IMPORTRANGE` function. I tried using the formula below but it's saying

> formula parse error

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECEMY6zdrIHrtJhvwLm0XnyP4AYOp4YnZ_bp9azLNyM/edit?usp=sharing

```
=QUERY( 
{ 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'Termination Review'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'2nd Week Warning'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'In Review'!A2:O"); }, 

"Select Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 ORDER BY Col1 ASC",1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the final semicolon after the third importrange. If I take this out, then I just get another error because I can't access your sheet:

```
=QUERY( 
{ 
IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'Termination Review'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'2nd Week Warning'!A2:O"); 

IMPORTRANGE("11Vm7p_0Tx_DI649kdrHuxMaK5wauuI281175hfwBqRo", "'In Review'!A2:O") }, 

"Select Col1, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 ORDER BY Col1 ASC",1 )
```